# ListView not displaying all data in database

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, listview

I feel like this is a bit of a noob question and I'm missing something obvious but I'm just getting used to Android programming and I have come across an issue with a SQLiteDatabase and ListView.

Earlier on today I created a ListView which displays a fixture list from a database.  I got it working, saved and left it.  I've come back to it and added some more fixtures into the database, however when I re-run the app only the first 4 fixtures continue to appear (the ones I created initially) when there is 18 fixtures.

Here is the FixtureDB class:

```
public class FixturesDB extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

//Database name
private static String dbname = "fixtureList";
//Database version
private static int version = 1;
//Primary key field
public static final String KEY_ROW_ID = "_id";
//Field which stores the fixture data
public static final String KEY_DATE = "fixture_date";
//Field which stores the fixture team
public static final String KEY_TEAM = "fixture_team";
//Field which stores the fixture competition
public static final String KEY_COMPETITION = "fixture_competition";
//Constant to store the table name
public static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "fixture_table";
//Instance variable for SQLiteDatabase
private SQLiteDatabase mDB;

//Constructor method
public FixturesDB(Context context) {
    super(context, dbname, null, version);
    this.mDB = getWritableDatabase();
}

/**
 * This method is called providing the database does not exist
 */
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String sql = "create table " + DATABASE_TABLE + " ( " + KEY_ROW_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement , "
            + KEY_DATE + " text , " + KEY_TEAM + " text , " + KEY_COMPETITION + " text ) ";
    db.execSQL(sql);
    sql = "insert into " + DATABASE_TABLE + " ( " + KEY_DATE + "," + KEY_TEAM + "," + KEY_COMPETITION + " ) "
            + " values ( '04/02/2015', 'Bolton', 'FA Cup' )";
    db.execSQL(sql);
    sql = "insert into " + DATABASE_TABLE + " ( " + KEY_DATE + "," + KEY_TEAM + "," + KEY_COMPETITION + " ) "
            + " values ( '07/02/2015', 'Everton', 'Premier League' )";
    db.execSQL(sql);
    sql = "insert into " + DATABASE_TABLE + " ( " + KEY_DATE + "," + KEY_TEAM + "," + KEY_COMPETITION + " ) "
            + " values ( '10/02/2015', 'Tottenham', 'Premier League' )";
    db.execSQL(sql);
    sql = "insert into " + DATABASE_TABLE + " ( " + KEY_DATE + "," + KEY_TEAM + "," + KEY_COMPETITION + " ) "
            + " values ( '19/02/2015', 'Besiktas', 'Europa League' )";
    db.execSQL(sql);
    sql = "insert into " + DATABASE_TABLE + " ( " + KEY_DATE + "," + KEY_TEAM + "," + KEY_COMPETITION + " ) "
            + " values ( '22/02/2015', 'Southampton', 'Premier League' )";
    db.execSQL(sql);
    sql = "insert into " + DATABASE_TABLE + " ( " + KEY_DATE + "," + KEY_TEAM + "," + KEY_COMPETITION + " ) "
            + " values ( '26/02/2015', 'Besiktas', 'Europa League' )";
    db.execSQL(sql);
    sql = "insert into " + DATABASE_TABLE + " ( " + KEY_DATE + "," + KEY_TEAM + "," + KEY_COMPETITION + " ) "
            + " values ( '01/03/2015', 'Man City', 'Premier League' )";
    db.execSQL(sql);
    sql = "insert into " + DATABASE_TABLE + " ( " + KEY_DATE + "," + KEY_TEAM + "," + KEY_COMPETITION + " ) "
            + " values ( '04/03/2015', 'Burnley', 'Premier League' )";
    db.execSQL(sql);
    sql = "insert into " + DATABASE_TABLE + " ( " + KEY_DATE + "," + KEY_TEAM + "," + KEY_COMPETITION + " ) "
            + " values ( '16/03/2015', 'Swansea', 'Premier League' )";
    db.execSQL(sql);
    sql = "insert into " + DATABASE_TABLE + " ( " + KEY_DATE + "," + KEY_TEAM + "," + KEY_COMPETITION + " ) "
            + " values ( '22/03/2015', 'Man Utd', 'Premier League' )";
    db.execSQL(sql);
    sql = "insert into " + DATABASE_TABLE + " ( " + KEY_DATE + "," + KEY_TEAM + "," + KEY_COMPETITION + " ) "
            + " values ( '04/04/2015', 'Arsenal', 'Premier League' )";
    db.execSQL(sql);
    sql = "insert into " + DATABASE_TABLE + " ( " + KEY_DATE + "," + KEY_TEAM + "," + KEY_COMPETITION + " ) "
            + " values ( '11/04/2015', 'Newcastle', 'Premier League' )";
    db.execSQL(sql);
    sql = "insert into " + DATABASE_TABLE + " ( " + KEY_DATE + "," + KEY_TEAM + "," + KEY_COMPETITION + " ) "
            + " values ( '18/04/2015', 'Hull', 'Premier League' )";
    db.execSQL(sql);
    sql = "insert into " + DATABASE_TABLE + " ( " + KEY_DATE + "," + KEY_TEAM + "," + KEY_COMPETITION + " ) "
            + " values ( '25/04/2015', 'West Brom', 'Premier League' )";
    db.execSQL(sql);
    sql = "insert into " + DATABASE_TABLE + " ( " + KEY_DATE + "," + KEY_TEAM + "," + KEY_COMPETITION + " ) "
            + " values ( '02/05/2015', 'QPR', 'Premier League' )";
    db.execSQL(sql);
    sql = "insert into " + DATABASE_TABLE + " ( " + KEY_DATE + "," + KEY_TEAM + "," + KEY_COMPETITION + " ) "
            + " values ( '09/05/2015', 'Chelsea', 'Premier League' )";
    db.execSQL(sql);
    sql = "insert into " + DATABASE_TABLE + " ( " + KEY_DATE + "," + KEY_TEAM + "," + KEY_COMPETITION + " ) "
            + " values ( '16/05/2015', 'Crystal Palace', 'Premier League' )";
    db.execSQL(sql);
    sql = "insert into " + DATABASE_TABLE + " ( " + KEY_DATE + "," + KEY_TEAM + "," + KEY_COMPETITION + " ) "
            + " values ( '24/05/2015', 'Stoke', 'Premier League' )";
    db.execSQL(sql);
}

/**
 * Returns all the fixtures in the database
 */
public Cursor getFixtures() {
    return mDB.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] { KEY_ROW_ID, KEY_DATE, KEY_TEAM, KEY_COMPETITION } 
    , null, null, null, null, KEY_TEAM + " asc ");
}


@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" + dbname);
    onCreate(db);   
}
```

}

The FixtureContentProvider class:

```
public class FixtureContentProvider extends ContentProvider{

public static final String PROVIDER_NAME = "com.example.project.fixture";


public static final Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://" + PROVIDER_NAME + "/fixtures" );


private static final int fixture = 1;

private static final UriMatcher uriMatcher ;
static {
    uriMatcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
    uriMatcher.addURI(PROVIDER_NAME, "fixtures", fixture);
}


FixturesDB mDB;


@Override
public boolean onCreate() {
    mDB = new FixturesDB(getContext());
    return true;
}

@Override
public String getType(Uri uri) {
    return null;
}


@Override
public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {

    if(uriMatcher.match(uri)==fixture){
        return mDB.getFixtures();
    }else{
        return null;
    }
}

@Override
public int delete(Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues values) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String selection,
        String[] selectionArgs) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}
```

}

and the Fixtures class:

```
public class Fixtures extends FragmentActivity implements LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter;
ListView listView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_fixtures);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);      
    mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getBaseContext(),  R.layout.listview_fixtures_layout, null,
            new String[] {FixturesDB.KEY_DATE, FixturesDB.KEY_TEAM, FixturesDB.KEY_COMPETITION},
            new int[] {R.id.date, R.id.team, R.id.competition}, 0);
    listView.destroyDrawingCache();
    listView.setVisibility(ListView.INVISIBLE);
    listView.setVisibility(ListView.VISIBLE);
    listView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    /**
     * This creates a loader to populate the list view from the sqlite database
     */
    getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);        
}


@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int arg0, Bundle arg1) {
    Uri uri = FixtureContentProvider.CONTENT_URI;
    return new CursorLoader(this, uri, null, null, null, null);
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> arg0, Cursor arg1) {
    mAdapter.swapCursor(arg1);
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> arg0) {
    mAdapter.swapCursor(null);
}
```

}

I assume I have to refresh or close the database then re-open or something like that?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit**
I've answered my own question by simply un-installing the app and re-installing it to the device.

Noob moment.

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the stub implementation of your content provider, it seems you must be assuming that if you add more insert statements to your onCreate method for your SQLiteOpenHelper that the new rows will show up in your fixtures table.

This is not the case.

The reason is that onCreate is only called once when your database is first created (no database file on the file system yet exists.)

To get around this for testing, you could delete your database file which is usually located in /data/data/your.package.name/databases and then re-run your app.

Or

Finish implementing your content provider and execute insert statements from some client code using a ContentResolver or ContentProviderClient.

Or

Use adb shell and insert rows into your database using the sqlite3 tool.